Notion of prime congruences
We have the idea of a prime ideal in a commutative ring $R$ but in universal algebra, we generalize the notion of ideal to that of a congruence. I’ve thought over the question of what a prime congruence would look like and all I could say is that maximal (proper) congruences should be prime and the trivial congruence shouldn’t be. Given the importance of prime ideals, I’d imagine someone’s put thought into how this would generalize though I haven’t been able to find anything.
I ask this question because I’m thinking about that the spectrum of a (commutative?) algebraic structure would look like in general. Any pointers would be helpful.
(Should I put the AG tag here?)

I have no idea what it should be (a "prime" normal subgroup) in the case of groups.

I’m considering defining them as congruences theta for which $V(\theta)$ is irreducible in the Zariski topology.

What's a prime congruence?
The lattice of ideals of a commutative ring has three well-studied operations:


 Sum: $I+J$

 Intersection: $I\cap J$

 Product: $I\cdot J$.



Primeness is defined with the third operation: $P$ is prime
if $I\cdot J\subseteq P$ implies $I\subseteq P$ or $J\subseteq P$.
For general algebraic structures, we have three corresponding
operations on congruences:

 Join: $\alpha\vee \beta$

 Meet or Intersection: $\alpha\wedge \beta = \alpha\cap \beta$

 Commutator: $[\alpha,\beta]$.



General primeness is defined in terms of the commutator operation:
congruence $\pi$ is prime
if $[\alpha,\beta]\subseteq \pi$ implies $\alpha\subseteq \pi$ or
$\beta\subseteq \pi$.
You can find this definition (for congruence modular varieties) on page 64 of
Freese, Ralph; McKenzie, Ralph,
Commutator theory for congruence modular varieties.
London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 125. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1987.
Remark: for noncommutative rings, $[I,J] = IJ+JI$.
For groups or Lie algebras, $[I,J]$ is the usual commutator of
normal subgroups or Lie ideals.
Since you are thinking about the spectrum, let me point you to
a couple of papers:
Agliano, Paolo,
The prime spectrum of a universal algebra.
Riv. Mat. Pura Appl. No. 5 (1989), 97-105.
Georgescu, George; Mureşan, Claudia,
Going up and lying over in congruence-modular algebras.
Math. Slovaca 69 (2019), no. 2, 275-296.

Does primeness defined in terms of the commutator agree with the notion of primeness from The shape of congruence lattices? (Maybe this is obvious, my coffee hasn't kicked in yet.)

@NoahSchweber: Yes, the concepts agree in the context where the black triangle is defined, namely for varieties with a weak difference term. In that monograph, the black triangle relation is more important than the notion of primeness. We use black triangle for the main arguments of that chapter, but then note in an appendix to Chapter 6 that black triangle has a connection to the more familiar concept of primeness.

Somewhat relatedly, do you think I should delete my answer? In light of yours I worry that mine is misleading.

@NoahSchweber: I see no reason for you to delete your answer.

Is there a notion of product of congruences in general? I’d imagine the way to eliminate $+$ is to replace it with $\vee$ but what about the product?

@LaveCave: The commutator of congruences IS a product of congruences. It is a common generalization of the product of ideals in a commutative ring and the commutator of normal subgroups of a group, but the commutator operation is defined for any algebraic structure.

@KeithKearnes how is the commutator defined in general?

@LaveCave: The definition of the general commutator is Definition 2.20 of https://math.colorado.edu/~kearnes/Papers/cong.pdf   You will have to read pages 27-31 for this definition to make sense.

Primeness is not a statement purely in terms of congruences; the naive translation also gives special treatment to the binary operation $\cdot$ and the nullary operation $0$. Given an algebra $\mathfrak{A}$, a binary term $*$, and a nullary term $c$ in the relevant language, we can define a $(*,c)$-prime congruence on $\mathfrak{A}$ as one satisfying $a*b\approx c$ (or maybe "$a*b\approx c*c$" is more natural?) iff $a\approx c$ or $b\approx c$; however, it's not clear how to find the "right" $*$ and $c$ in a given algebra. Moreover, and more importantly I think, there's no particular reason to expect this notion to be important in general algebras.
That said, there is at least one notion of "prime congruence" in the literature. In the book Kearnes/Kiss, The shape of congruence lattices, the authors introduce the following notion: a congruence $\theta$ on an algebra ${\bf A}$ is prime iff $\theta$ is meet-irreducible in $\mathrm{Con}({\bf A})$ and additionally $\theta\blacktriangleleft 1$. This latter condition is a bit of a definition chase, and the relevant pages are 27/28, 126, and 147. This notion does generalize that of prime ideals from ring theory (in the sense that in a commutative unital ring $R$, an ideal $I$ is prime iff the corresponding congruence $\approx_I$ is Kearnes/Kiss-prime). However, I think the technical detail needed to make sense of the definition indicates just how special the setting of rings is; I suspect that we should not in general expect KK-primeness to have a simple description in general (even natural) classes of algebras rather than rings.
